Dictionary input in dataframe column
I'm trying to read a file with multiple columns. One such column is named 'answer', containing values that pretty much are Python dictionaries.
Values include:
{'number': '2', 'date': {'day': '', 'month': '', 'year': ''}, 'spans': []}

and
{'number': '', 'date': {'day': '', 'month': '', 'year': ''}, 'spans': ['4-yard', '31-yard']}

A particular row's value in the 'answer' column is when printed onto the console displayed as
'{\'number\': \'\', \'date\': {\'day\': \'\', \'month\': \'\', \'year\': \'\'}, \'spans\': ["Barlow\'s 1-yard touchdown run", \'2-yard touchdown run\', \'by rookie RB Joseph Addai.\']}'

In the csv, it looks like
{'number': '', 'date': {'day': '', 'month': '', 'year': ''}, 'spans': ["Barlow's 1-yard touchdown run", '2-yard touchdown run', 'by rookie RB Joseph Addai.']}

After conversion to a valid JSON string and printed onto the console, it looks like
'{"number": "", "date": {"day": "", "month": "", "year": ""}, "spans": ["Barlow"s 1-yard touchdown run", "2-yard touchdown run", "by rookie RB Joseph Addai."]}'

To convert the strings to dictionaries, I tried using the json.loads(string) method.
Here is what I did:
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    dict = df.iloc[i]['answer']
    dict = dict.replace("'", '"')
    # To convert it to a valid JSON string
    dict = json.loads(dict)
    ans[i] = dict['number']

The following error appears for the third example given above, but not the other two:
JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 80 (char 79)

It fails to convert the string into a dictionary for reasons unknown to me.
What can I do to rectify this error?
Is there any method to read the 'answer' column as a dictionary, instead of having to read it as a string and then convert said string to a dictionary?

Your error JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 80 (char 79)  comes from the 'Barlow"s' piece. Do you know if there are many instances where " comes alone?

As I mentioned in my comment, your error  JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 80 (char 79)  comes from the 'Barlow"s'. Now, to avoid these errors you'll need to replace any instances of " occuring between letters. Here is a function that will handle these cases.
import pandas as pd
import json
import re

data = {
    'answer': [
        "{'number': '2', 'date': {'day': '', 'month': '', 'year': ''}, 'spans': []}",
        "{'number': '', 'date': {'day': '', 'month': '', 'year': ''}, 'spans': ['4-yard', '31-yard']}",
        '{\'number\': \'\', \'date\': {\'day\': \'\', \'month\': \'\', \'year\': \'\'' \
        '}, \'spans\': ["Barlow\'s 1-yard touchdown run", "2-yard touchdown run", "by rookie RB Joseph Addai."]}'
    ]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def clean_and_convert(string):
    try:
        modified = string.replace("'", '"')
        modified = re.sub(r'(?<!\\)"', r'\\"', modified) 
        modified = modified.replace('\\"', '"') 
        modified = re.sub(r'(\w)"(\w)', r'\1\\" \2', modified)
        
        print("Final modified string for JSON loading:", modified)
        
        return json.loads(modified)
    except json.JSONDecodeError as e:
        print("Error processing string:", string)
        print("Modified string that caused error:", modified)
        raise e

df['converted'] = df['answer'].apply(clean_and_convert)

df[['answer', 'converted']]

This will gives you:
                                             answer  \
0  {'number': '2', 'date': {'day': '', 'month': '...   
1  {'number': '', 'date': {'day': '', 'month': ''...   
2  {'number': '', 'date': {'day': '', 'month': ''...   

                                           converted  
0  {'number': '2', 'date': {'day': '', 'month': '...  
1  {'number': '', 'date': {'day': '', 'month': ''...  
2  {'number': '', 'date': {'day': '', 'month': ''...  

Here is the print-out of the changes
Final modified string for JSON loading: {"number": "2", "date": {"day": "", "month": "", "year": ""}, "spans": []}
Final modified string for JSON loading: {"number": "", "date": {"day": "", "month": "", "year": ""}, "spans": ["4-yard", "31-yard"]}
Final modified string for JSON loading: {"number": "", "date": {"day": "", "month": "", "year": ""}, "spans": ["Barlow\" s 1-yard touchdown run", "2-yard touchdown run", "by rookie RB Joseph Addai."]}


This one threw up issues in examples like
{'number': '', 'date': {}, 'spans': ["An interception off Broncos' quarterback Trevor Siemian by cornerback Logan Ryan resulted in the only touchdown of the game—a 1-yard run by Patriots' running back LeGarrette Blount in the second quarter"]}
Converted, it looks like
{"number": "", "date": {}, "spans": ["An interception off Broncos" quarterback Trevor Siemian by cornerback Logan Ryan resulted in the only touchdown of the game—a 1-yard run by Patriots" running back LeGarrette Blount in the second quarter"]}
eval() worked perfectly

I came to know that the format of the strings while looking like a JSON dictionary, matched perfectly with the format of a Python dictionary and could easily be parsed with the in-built eval() function.
Using the template of Serge above,
def convert(string):
    try:
        string = eval(string)
        return string
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error processing string:", string)
        raise e

converted = df['answer'].apply(convert)

print(converted)

Which printed
0        {'number': '19', 'date': {'day': '', 'month': ...
1        {'number': '2', 'date': {'day': '', 'month': '...
2        {'number': '99.9', 'date': {'day': '', 'month'...
3        {'number': '29826', 'date': {'day': '', 'month...
4        {'number': '30', 'date': {'day': '', 'month': ...
                               ...                        
60852    {'number': '', 'date': {'day': '', 'month': ''...
60853    {'number': '', 'date': {'day': '', 'month': ''...
60854    {'number': '', 'date': {'day': '', 'month': ''...
60855    {'number': '', 'date': {'day': '', 'month': ''...
60856    {'number': '', 'date': {'day': '', 'month': ''...
Name: answer, Length: 60857, dtype: object

with absolutely no errors.
